# Feynman Trick Demonstration for $ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(1-\alpha^2x^2 \right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

I've been tracking [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3445949/help-proving-the-convergence-of-the-integral-int-01-frac-ln1-alpha-2x2) today on math.SE where the OP was asking for a proof of convergence for the integral

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(1-\alpha^2x^2 \right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx.
$$

I want to ask a related but distinct question of **how to explicitly compute the value of this integral.**  Something I had learned of today for the first time was the **Feynman trick** for evaluating integrals with some parameter $\alpha$ included in it (here is a helpful [link](http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf)).  Essentially what this comes down to is interpreting the result of this integral as a function of $\alpha$:
$$
f(\alpha) \;\; =\;\; \int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(1-\alpha^2x^2 \right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx.
$$

Feynman's approach to solving this was to essentially uncover a differential equation for $f$ by first differentiating this expression with respect to $\alpha$:

$$
\frac{df}{d\alpha} \;\; =\;\; \int_0^1\frac{-2\alpha x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2} \left (1-\alpha^2x^2\right )}dx.
$$

Next we fix an initial condition for this differential equation by picking a value for $\alpha$ that makes our original integral easy to compute.  For instance, $\alpha=0$ yields:
$$
f(0) \;\; =\;\; \int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(1 \right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx \;\; =\;\; 0,
$$

and then to proceed with finding $\frac{df}{d\alpha}$ via the integral expression determined above.  Plugging this into Wolfram Alpha shows us that

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(1-\alpha^2x^2 \right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx \;\; =\;\; -\pi\ln \left (\frac{2}{1+ \sqrt{1-\alpha^2}} \right )
$$

but I would like some guidance on how to actually compute this integral.  I had never heard of this method until today and am quite intrigued by how it works.

**Note:** I did a quick scan of all Feynman integral posts on here and I didn't see an example where the integrand included a square-root expression in the denominator.  If I am mistaken I will gladly remove this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let $x=\sin t$,

$$
I(\alpha)=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(1-\alpha^2x^2 \right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(1-\alpha^2 \sin^2 t)dt 
$$

\begin{align}
I'(\alpha) =& \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{-2\alpha\sin^2 t}{1-\alpha^2 \sin^2 t}dt \\
=&\ \frac2{\alpha}\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(1-\frac{1}{1-\alpha^2 \sin^2 t}\right)dt 
= \frac{\pi}{\alpha} - \frac{\pi}{\alpha\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}} 
\end{align}

Thus

$$I(\alpha) = \int_0^{\alpha} I'(s)ds=
\pi \int_0^{\alpha}\left( \frac1{s} -\frac{1}{s\sqrt{1-s^2}}\right)ds
=\pi \ln\left(1+\sqrt{1-s^2}\right)_0^{\alpha}$$
$$=\pi\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}2$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Other than the general steps of finding $\frac{df}{d\alpha}$, are there general principles by which you rearrange functions to compute the derivatives?  The computations seem rather ad hoc otherwise.

Comment: @Mnifldz - The steps presented in the answer is intended to illustrate the Feynman technique. It may seem ad hoc otherwise, but only because certain non-essential steps are skipped. A smooth presentation would have been quite lengthy. For example, the last integral $\int_0^{\alpha}\frac{1}{s\sqrt{1-s^2}}ds$ could be carried out quiet naturally with a few more steps.

Comment: That's fine.  I understand how all of the computations were made, no confusion there.  I was just wondering, in addition to the technique itself, if there were underlying methods to carry out the integrals themselves.